# Place gameObjects on top of another gameObject in Inspector

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to script to place two of my instantiated gameObjects on top of another gameObject.
For example in the image given below, I am instantiating two objects and making "Buttons-Set" as their parent. I want the two cloned objects to come on top of "Other" gameObject in the inspector window. How do I achieve this?

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
   GameObject myChild = Instantiate (prefab);
   myChild.transform.parent = parentOfChild.transform;
   myChild.transform.localPosition = new Vector3 (0, 0, 0);
}
```

[image: PlaceObjs]

Comment: What have you tried to change the order of the children. Why is child order important?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the order in the hierarchy with [SetSiblingIndex](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.SetSiblingIndex.html) -  :)

```
transform.SetSiblingIndex(0);
```